# Find empty directory in Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux

I am trying to find all empty directory using find command and also using alpinelinux , but unfortunately we don't have any option of action as empty in alpine. Anyone have any suggestion on how can achieve this.

I am trying to use below
find . -depth -type d -empty -mmin +120 -print;

Anyone can suggest if any package/library can solve this issue .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may google `how to check empty dir in shell` and execute a subshell for each directory and make the subshell exit with zero exit status if the directory is empty:

```
find . -depth -type d -exec sh -c '[ -z "$(ls -A "$1")" ]' _ {} \; -print
```

Other then that, install [GNU find](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/findutils).